# Error: Invalid hook call api FlatList react-native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, use-effect

I have a error on my react-native project, I use typescript and expo. So, when I use useEffect() to get api response to FlatList I receive this error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv2oe.png)

My code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  FlatList
} from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import styles from './styles';

function Products() {
    
    const [apiProduct, setProduct] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://laravel-api.com/v1/product',{
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Accept'        : 'application/json'
                },
        })
        .then(response =>response.json())
        .then(data => {
                setProduct(data.data)
            })
    }, []);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            
            <Text style={styles.title1}>
                {"Produtos mais Buscados"} {"\n"}
            </Text>

            <SafeAreaView>
                    <FlatList 
                        data={apiProduct}
                        keyExtractor={(apiProduct) => apiProduct }
                        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                        renderItem={viewProduct}
                    ></FlatList>
            </SafeAreaView>

        </View>
    );
}

function viewProduct(item) {
    
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const { id, name, price, category_name, img_url } = item.item
    const imgUrl = "https://s3.url.com/" + img_url;

    return (
        <View style={styles.prodList}>
            <Image source={{ uri: imgUrl }} style={styles.prodImage} /> 
            <TouchableOpacity 
                style={styles.prodName}
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate('productView', {
                      itemId: id,
                    });
                  }}>
                <Text>{name} {"\n"} </Text>
                <Text style={styles.prodCategory}>{category_name.toUpperCase() } {"\n"}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.prodPrice}>{"R$ " + price }</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Products;
```

but, if I remove the navigation method **navigation.navigate('productView', {itemId: id});**, this error desapear.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a function for your `renderItem` on your flat list. This means your `viewProduct` is just a function and not a component. As the error says, you need to have a component if you want to use hooks. You can fix this by making the function a component and then add it to `renderItem` as one.

```
<FlatList
    data={apiProduct}
    keyExtractor={(apiProduct) => apiProduct}
    contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <ViewProduct {...item} />}
/>
```

Make sure you capitalize your `ViewProduct` since it will be a component now.

Another option is to call `useNavigation` on your `Products` component and pass a function to your `viewProduct` function and use that for your `onPress`.